# Finding the point on the progressbar where the surface was clicked

Tags: android, progress-bar, media-player, audio-streaming

I have a progressbar that displays the amount of audio already played.

If the user clicks on the  progressbar I want to start the audio playback from that point. 
Similar to mediaplayers on desktops.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should use a [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) and implement your own [OnSeekBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html).

The [onStopTrackingTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html#onStopTrackingTouch%28android.widget.SeekBar%29) indicates that the touch event is finished, you can so get the progress by calling getProgress() on the Seekbar.

Hope it helps

Jokahero